# How can I pass variables from a Perl script to a Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, perl

I got the duty to make a fix to an ancient Perl script our company uses, I haven't even looked at Perl in about 20 years. So I want to pick up a couple of the variables, and dump them to the environment so something like...

So let's say the script does a thing, say generates a total, and saves it as a variable $total, I want to be able to pull $total up in my bash script and keep chugging along with it while basically exiting the perl script.

How would I do that?

Comment: Append them to a text file?

Comment: If the perl script calls the bash script then you can do `$ENV{total}=$total` and the bash script will see it.   If the perl script ends and then the bash script starts then you need to store the results elsewhere; it will depend on how the two scripts are called.

Comment: why not just modify the perl script to do whatever it is you want to do in bash?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

modify the Perl's script to display an output that can be easily parsable via a wrapper script:

```
print "###$total###";
```

Then in the shell wrapper script with `GNU grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

total=$(./script.pl | grep -oP '###\K[\d,.]+(?=###))
echo "$total"
```

---

Another way, using temp file

```
open my $fh, ">", '/tmp/specific_file_name_with_total'
    or die $!;

print $fh $total;

close $fh;
```

Then is [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
#!/bin/bash

total=$(< /tmp/specific_file_name_with_total)
echo "$total"
```